# Traffic lights on a SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: list, calculated-column

I'm trying to set up a Traffic List priority list on my SharePoint 2010 list. I'm following this Blog: https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/. I get to point 5 and in the Insert Column list I'm not getting 'Category'. I set up a Priority Indicator Field [image: Traffic Light SharePoint List]. So on the right of the screen grab is what I've done and on the left is from the Blog.

Nothing so showing up in the Priority Indicator column after I save it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you are not using the correct reference marks `"` and correct apostrophes `'`.

If the formula is directly copy+pasted from the source, there might occur a formatting issue which changes the `"` marks to `”` and `'` marks to `’`, which neither of are understood by SharePoint. Try to type the correct reference marks and apostrophes by hand to your formula.

---

Edit: based on the comments, also other suggestions have been given:

- Use `•` instead of `&bull;`
- Confirm that the list items have a selected `Priority` in the `Priority`-column

Comment: Cheers. tried that, I also copied and pasted it into NotePad and back again and it hasn't worked.

Comment: @Dazza Copy+pasting it through e.g. Notepad doesn't change a thing, as the incorrect marks would not be reformatted. They *need* to be manually fixed. Also you could try to replace `&bull;` by the direct ASCII-symbol: `•`.

Comment: Also just a simple check: as you mention "nothing showing up", have you actually defined priorities for your list items in the `Priority` column? Are they using values such as `1` or `2`?

Comment: After I pasted the formula in from Notepad I put the punctuation in manually. 

I created the Priority column as a Choice menu but no I haven't set up any defined priorities.  I'll take a look at how to do that.

Comment: Should the Priority Column actually be a Column type in SP?

Comment: Let me clarify: You should have two columns for the traffic light feature: `Priority` and `Priority Indicator`. `Priority` is to be a Choice-type of column with options for values `(1) High`, `(2) Normal` and `(3) Low`. `Priority Indicator` column is to be a Calculated Column with the formula as shown in the example. When you add a list item, it needs to have the `Priority` value of either of 1, 2 or 3 so that it has some priority to indicate by a color in the `Priority Indicator` column.

Comment: Another **crucial** thing I need to confirm: have you actually followed the MOSS 2007 implementation steps? Because by following the SP 2010 steps of the blog (listed below the MOSS 2007 steps), you should get to the point where the raw HTML is shown, which is later fixed by an XSL-change as detailed in the blog.

Comment: Thanks Moe, I came to that understanding just about the time you posted! So now I have the Priority Indicator set up as a calculated field with the formula, and the Priority Column is set up as a choice column with 1 High 2 Normal 3 Low and now the Priority Indicator column is showing '#Name?'

Comment: No followed the SP2010 implementation instructions

Comment: `#Name?`-value can show up for many reasons, but basically it's indicating there's something wrong with the formula you have used.

Comment: Oddly enough when I put: 
    ="<DIV style=’font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&CHOOSE(RIGHT(LEFT(Priority,2),1),"red","orange","green")&";’>&bull;</DIV>" in it default to ="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&CHOOSE(RIGHT(LEFT(#NAME?,2),1),"red","orange","green")&";'>•</DIV>" and now it returns '#VALUE!'

in

Answer (score 2):

I tried this solution out in a tucked away area on the live environment and it worked, so I think there's a problem between our live and dev sits causing the problem.